# why my code doesnt run right? whats the promble of this if statment?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

iam desiging a web site that can change the prices
 when for first time i click on slider the price become 19.99 and for the next time my price become 199.99.
my project is this https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/pricing-component-with-toggle-8vPwRMIC

im using a variable if the variable ==1 then change the price to 199.99 and when the variable ==2 then change price to 19.99 ; but every time i click the price stays on 19.99:/

```js
$(function(){
    var m = 1;
    $(".switch").click(function(){
        if(m == 1){
            alert("hi");
        $("#h1").html("$199.99");
        $("#h2").html("$249.99");
        $("#h3").html("$399.99");
            m = 0;
        } else{
            alert("bye");
            $("#h1").html("$19.99");
        $("#h2").html("$24.99");
        $("#h3").html("$39.99");
            m = 0;
        }
        
    });
    
});
```

when i click both hi and bye alerts ,alerted and i dont know why ???:///
 the return statment in if block also doesn't the solution, i tried.

Comment: where is `prices` defined/set?

Comment: it is not clear in the question where is `price` is coming from , please add the relevant parts of the code

Comment: can you tell me what exactly is the price in this code?

Comment: if the problem is because of slider then for sure i can help you out

Comment: Sadeq, great to see you here, trying to help others. I'm having trouble understanding your question, could you update the title to be very specific about the problem. The title is very generic and does not specify which language or library you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hi sadeq, switch is reserved word, change class switch to name related

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda I agree that we shouldn't use reserved keywords however the issue is not with the reserved keyword, it is with the passing `prices` value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your limited code, I tried recreating it:

> Looks like you're not passing `prices` values correctly, the `if` and `else` conditions are correct, you can change the values in the first line and try checking it, I was able to run both the conditions. The issues seems you're not sending the correct values to `prices`.

```js
var prices = 0; /* change to you values here from 0 to 1 */

$(document).ready(function() {
  var m = 1;
  $(".divSwitch").click(function() {
    if (prices == 1) {
      alert("hi");
      $("#h1").html("$199.99");
      $("#h2").html("$249.99");
      $("#h3").html("$399.99");
      m = 0;
    } else {
      alert("bye");
      $("#h1").html("$19.99");
      $("#h2").html("$24.99");
      $("#h3").html("$39.99");
      m = 0;
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.divSwitch {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divSwitch" sytle="height:50px;width:50px;background-color:red;">Click here.
  <div id="h1"></div>
  <div id="h2"></div>
  <div id="h3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I think price ain't defined.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".switch").click(function(){
if(document.getElementById('isAgeSelected').checked) {
        
        $("#h1").html("$199.99");
      $("#h2").html("$249.99");
      $("#h3").html("$399.99");
    } else {
        
         $("#h1").html("$19.99");
      $("#h2").html("$24.99");
      $("#h3").html("$39.99");
    }
    
 });
 $(document).ready(function(){
 if(document.getElementById('isAgeSelected').checked) {
        
        $("#h1").html("$199.99");
      $("#h2").html("$249.99");
      $("#h3").html("$399.99");
    } else {
        
         $("#h1").html("$19.99");
      $("#h2").html("$24.99");
      $("#h3").html("$39.99");
    }
 });
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected" value="Yes">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label> 

 <div id="h1"></div>
  <div id="h2"></div>
  <div id="h3"></div>
```

I HOPE THIS MIGHT SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM IN A EASY WAY